# Are there any other words that contain 짱 in the same way as '얼짱'?

Tags: vocabulary

얼짱 means something like 'top face' and is presumably a contraction of '얼굴' with '짱'.

몸짱 Also seems to be possible (seeming to refer to bodybuilders!)

Is this form restricted to these cases, or are others possible?

Comment: SM Entertainment used to have a public audition-contest where they awarded "노래짱", "댄스짱', "외모짱", and "연기짱'. "-짱" seems to be a very productive suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the word '짱' originates is not known for sure. Some say it was derived from '장군 장 (將)' which means a general (in the military) and '장 (not 짱)' was used to describe a student who fought the best in a fist fight among students in middle and high school and the pronunciation changed from [장] to [짱] to make it sound stronger.

When you hear "철수가 이 학교에서 짱이래," it means

> I heard 철수 is the best (fist) fighter in this school.

Some say it was derived from '길 장 (長)' which means *long*, head (of a group), an (oldest) adult.

Whatever the etymology is, you can put it virtually anywhere such as

> 몸매짱 (best body especially for women), 싸움짱 (best fighter), 얼굴짱 (best face, most handsome or beautiful
>   man/woman), 냄세짱 (best smell), 소리짱 (best sound), 노래짱 (best
>   song/signer), 대한민국짱 (Korea is the best), etc.

Answer (score 2):

"짱" is slang meaning "the best".  You can use it by itself:

> 이거 짱이에요 (This is the best) (from [Naver Dictionary](http://endic.naver.com/userEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=bd3720a81f33a35f42056e2d435434ff&query=%EC%A7%B1))

It is often added to other words to make new slang words, though perhaps most of them don't catch on as widely as 얼짱 and 몸짱.  [This list](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%EC%9D%98_%EC%9D%B8%ED%84%B0%EB%84%B7_%EC%8B%A0%EC%A1%B0%EC%96%B4_%EB%AA%A9%EB%A1%9D) includes a few:

> 춤짱, 킹왕짱, 노짱